# How to develop a site in JSP?

Tags: java, php, jsp

How can I create a site that users can manually make their own websites using my control panel in the site like Yola or Weebly that are free web developers. I think they use JSP but not sure. Can you help me that what kind of language they make those sites?

Comment: There's no "specific" language really, you can do it in any server side language you want to use....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any server-side language to develop a "site for making sites". PHP, Java (JSPs), Ruby/Rails, Python/Django... there are a lot of options. Some languages are better for certain tasks than others, but pretty much anything on the market would *suffice* for *creating* the website-making site.

As for "how to create" such a "site-building site":

- You would need to supply users with templates, tools to edit those
  templates, and ways to change the metadata about their sites.
- You would also need to provide hosting for your users. You might come
  in the form of subdomains, like jacksonssite.awesomewebsitemaker.com.
- You would also need to make sure that your templates create pages
  that are secure from "hackers" and the like.
- You might also need to create tutorials / hire a support staff, to
  help the technologically-illiterate use your tools.
- And many more things as well.

It would be a complex task. If you are a beginner to web programming, undertaking a project like this would be far too ambitious.